# 'null' is null or not a object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a line of code that doesn't work in IE8 and lower.

```
var mediaQueryId = getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" ).getPropertyValue("content");
var mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' ); // 'null' is null or not a object
```

I tried to use this fix in order to make it work but I get this error:

> 'null' is null or not a object

Here's my code:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
        this.el = el;
        this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
            var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
            if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
            if (re.test(prop)) {
                prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                    return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                });
            }
            return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The website is http://www.gablabelle.com/

Comment: And in which line do you get the error?

Comment: Search bar is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143326/currentstyle-in-ie-is-null, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722736/weird-ie-behavior-currentstyle-returns-null

Comment: @FelixKling added more infos to the post.

Comment: The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901115/applying-the-getcomputedstyle-fix-for-ie-to-my-code-null-is-null-or-not-a

Answer (score 0):

```
getComputedStyle = function(){
    return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
    //                           you are returning null ----^
}
```

...

```
getComputedStyle( ... ).getPropertyValue( ... )
null                   .getPropertyValue( ... )
```

null is null :)

Comment: I don't understand what I should change to my syntax... Trying to apply this fix: http://snipplr.com/view/13523/

Answer (score 0):

```
var mediaQueryId = getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" )
                      ?getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" ).getPropertyValue("content")
                      :'';
```

---

Or something like:

```
var foundStyle = getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" );
if (foundStyle) {
   var mediaQueryId = foundStyle.getPropertyValue("content") || '';
   mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' ); // 'null' is null or not a object
}
```

Comment: Also added more infos to the posts.

Comment: see the change `null`->`''`, you can't treat null as an object

Comment: I tried both... Still no luck... http://www.gablabelle.com/ if you try with IE8 you will see the error msg. The JS is at http://www.gablabelle.com/wp-content/themes/gablabelle/js/script.js

Comment: Just skimmed the code, but my guess is you don't have the Console (F12) open.  If so `console.log()` will give an object not found error.

Comment: Nope still the same error message. Commented out the console.log() accross the JS.

Comment: @Gab: I don't have IE8, so I can't debug this for you, but if you do: `var mediaQueryId = (getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" )
   ?getComputedStyle( document.body, ":after" ).getPropertyValue("content")
   :'') || '';`, does that get you anywhere?  I see you tried the first method, but this would be an alternative to the second method above.